# C# Close Form All Showing

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form, and call ShowDialog method (form2). After 2', application will logout and show form login. I want to close all form showing.

Comment: We are not able understand what you are asking for?. So please rewrite your question.

Comment: @Downvoters, being experienced professional one must try to understand that, some people will have language problem. Instead of simply down voting the questions, leave them a comment, so that they will understand their mistake and get a chance to correct.

Comment: Hi, fixed. Thanks  Rao Ehsan and all  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.OpenForm will be useful

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if(f.Name != "MainFormName")
    {
        // don't close main form
        f.Close();
    }
}
```